# How to detect which ports are not blocked in a local network

Tags: tomcat, port, firewall, blocked, local-network

I am trying to run tomcat in local network, I want to run a web service that can be visited by other computers in the same network. It was successful when I use wireless router to form a local network at home. But when I use school's wireless network, web service can't be visited by other computers. I suspect port 80 was blocked, so I try other ports, it doesn't either.

Is there any way to detect which ports are not blocked in the local network?

Comment: Before you go do this you should verify that it's not against school policy.  This could get you suspended or expelled.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on windows, to test whether port is open, try:

1.) Start -> Run

2.) telnet server-address port-number (note that server address can be ip of any other PC in network)

3.) If the window hangs while saying "Connecting ..." and then dies, the port is not accessible. And if the window instantly dies, the port is probably inaccessible. And if the window display some kind of text, like "220 ESMTP etc." the port is open.